# what is the difference between BigQuery and Storage on GCP?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Hi guys I am using GCP for the first time and while I  walking through the a project's  cloud function example with the mock data, I got confused about similarities/differences of each one and I would like more clarity of what makes them different because to me they seem so similar.

Comment: What do you find similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery#section-10) is a data warehouse and a SQL Engine. You can use it to store tabular data in datasets and tables. In the tables you may as well store more complex structures like arrays and JSONs but not files for example.

[Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/storage) is a blob storage, with functionality similar to what you know in your linux/windows machine (saving files, folders, deleting, copying). Of course that in the backend it's nothing like your local file system.

Answer (score 1):

`BigQuery` is a fully managed and serverless data warehouse. It's like `Snowflake` or `Redshift`.

`Google Cloud Storage(GCS)` is like `Amazon S3` or `Azure Storage`. Storages are for storing data as the name suggests.

You usually use `BigQuery` to analyze & query data in order to draw some insights. `BigQuery` is an analytical engine.

You can store images, videos, logs, files, and etc in `GCS(Google Cloud Storage)`, but `BigQuery` can't.

Answer (score -1):

Google BigQuery belongs to "Big Data as a Service" category of the tech stack, while Google Cloud Storage can be primarily classified under "Cloud Storage".

Some of the features offered by Google BigQuery are:

•   All behind the scenes- Your queries can execute asynchronously in the
background, and can be polled for status.

•   Import data with ease- Bulk load your data using Google Cloud Storage or stream it in bursts of up to 1,000 rows per second.

•   Affordable big data- The first Terabyte of data processed each month is free.

On the other hand, Google Cloud Storage provides the following key features:

•   High Capacity and Scalability

•   Strong Data Consistency

•   Google Developers Console Projects

"High Performance" is the primary reason why developers consider Google BigQuery over the competitors, whereas "Scalable" was stated as the key factor in picking Google Cloud Storage.